# Could I see some practical uses of the library commonsguy/cwac-richedit?

Tags: commonsware-cwac

Could I see some practical uses of the library commonsguy/cwac-richedit?

Can we do indenting and Bulleted/Numbered lists?

Comment: Please note that this is not an official forum for anyone's product; this looks like a question for the authors of the library, or for a different type of site. Take a look at the [help] for the kind of questions expected here.

Comment: I do not know what you consider "practical uses" to mean. There is basic support for bullets, but not numbered lists or indenting.

Comment: I mean is there an app in Google Play or is there a apk i can download that is using the library?

Comment: The project has [a demo app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit/tree/master/demo) that you are welcome to build and experiment with.